Where can I find a simple PeerJS example using AudioNodes?
I don't see any examples on the PeerJS website for audio connections:
https://peerjs.com/examples
The documentation mentions that a stream is returned:
https://peerjs.com/docs/#mediaconnection
Which I think I should be able to use with createMediaStreamSource:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource
I have some simple visualizers that I wire up the the audio before it goes out and when it comes back.  I clearly see the signal on the outbound side, but don't get anything on the inbound side.
// Caller

    callButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const outgoingStream = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
        inputSourceNode.connect(outgoingStream);
        const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
        inputSourceNode.connect(analyser);
        const canvas = document.getElementById('dupeSignal');
        const vu = new AudioVisualizer(canvas, analyser);
        vu.start();
        
        const call = peer.call(otherId, outgoingStream.stream);
        call.on('error', (err) => { 
          console.log(`Call error: ${err.message}`);
        });
        call.on('stream', (incomingStream) => {
            console.log('Call stream');
          if (!!peerSourceNode) {
              peerSourceNode.disconnect();
          }
          peerSourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(incomingStream);
          peerSourceNode.connect(peerAnalyser);
        });
    });

// Callee
    peer.on('call', function(call) {
        console.log('Peer call (call recieved)');
        const outgoingStream = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
        inputSourceNode.connect(outgoingStream);
        const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
        inputSourceNode.connect(analyser);
        const canvas = document.getElementById('dupeSignal');
        const vu = new AudioVisualizer(canvas, analyser);
        vu.start();
        call.answer(outgoingStream.stream);
        call.on('stream', function(incomingStream) {
            console.log('Stream Recieved');
            if (!!peerSourceNode) {
                peerSourceNode.disconnect();
            }
            peerSourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(incomingStream);
            peerSourceNode.connect(peerAnalyser);
        });
    });

I don't see any audio on either the Caller or Callee side.  My implementation of a very simple text chat works fine over the same P2P connection.

Based on this answer the problem here is limited to Chrome; Chrome won't send the audio unless there is an HTML element consuming it.  The analyzer does not count as a consumer.
The fix is to simply create a muted node that consumes it.  Add this code to both of your call.on('stream' ...  handlers.
        call.on('stream', function(incomingStream) {
            // Ungodly hack to actually get the audio to flow
            const a = new Audio();
            a.muted = true;
            a.srcObject = incomingStream;
            a.addEventListener('canplaythrough', () => { console.log('ready to flow'); });
            // End ungodly hack.
 [ ... Remaining code unchanged .. ]

Answering the initial question directly, you might find this walk-through on Medium helpful.
